# Using a RequestFactoryEditorDriver to update on the fly

Tags: gwt, editor, requestfactory

I have a text field that I want to save periodically as users type in it.  I'd like to hook it into my existing RequestFactoryEditorDriver framework, but I can't think of a way to do so.  The trouble is that I'd have to wait for all of my `driver.flush().fire()` calls to return before calling `edit()` again, so in the meantime the data would not be editable.

My best solution so far is to create an entire layer above the proxy. It would wait until it was just about to save, and then edit the proxy, copy in the changes, and persist the proxy, but at that point I'm losing most of the benefit of the Editor framework.  Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: If you could snapshot or branch the RequestContext and fire() the branched RC, would that give you the behavior that you're looking for?

Comment: That would be great.  Then `RequestFactoryEditorDriverWithBranching` could take care of that and I could just call `driver.flush().fire()` over and over again.  Making a good `Editor` that saves periodically is difficult right now because of all the fumbling with the driver necessary - especially if I'm trying to keep the driver in a presenter away from the view!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another thing that I believe would work, and probably wouldn't involve much more work (probably less actually) than Ray's answer: do not edit the object you want to save but a copy of it (created with `RequestContext.create()`), make a copy before you edit, and then flush and copy back to your bean (in another `RequestContext`) before firing.
This however presumes there won't be concurrent edits, because of the asynchronous communication with the server (the user can continue editing, and you'd have to detect and resolve "conflicts" if someone else edited the same object at the same time).
To make a copy, use `AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean` to get the bean out of the RF proxy, then an `AutoBeanVisitor` to visit all properties and copy their values into another proxy/autobean.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it wouldn't be too hard to tackle this at a lower level. E.g., put a wrapper around the RequestFactory itself that makes all void returns fire their call back synchronously, presuming that 99% of the time they really will succeed.

Comment: Interesting idea - are enough parts of the framework accessible for me to do this without intruding in the Google code?  To address a different concern I rewrote some of the `CellTable`, but then was burned when I wanted to upgrade to 2.2 and my reimplementation didn't fit in anymore.  RequestFactory has been harder to read than the cell stuff because of how much gets generated at compile time - my trusty F3 button in Eclipse doesn't work :(

Comment: Re: your CellTable stuff, patches are always welcome: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/makinggwtbetter.html. [gah, hit save too soon. Can't believe the enter key does that. More to com]